# How to align two TextView's horizontally using the BaseLine Constraint Handle in ConstraintLayout Android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have read about **ConstraintLayout** in Android, Now I have TextView's of different sizes , but I want to align the content of two textviews horizontally using the BaseLine Constraint Handle. How to achieve this in xml layout ?

This is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Hello World"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
      android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text1"
      android:textSize="50sp"
      android:text="Big Text"
      android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="24dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This can be set in the layout editor by dragging the baseline handle of the desired TextView to the baseline of another TextView.

or

This can be set in the xml using the **app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf** attribute

```
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/text1"
```

[Constraint Layout](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

[Useful link on Constraint Layout](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1#.olxzhxwkv)